# Failed queries in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql

Finding the failed queries in Azure SQL
Description: How can I get all the failed queries in Azure SQL for the last 5 days?
Use-case- I need to troubleshoot certain issues

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Extended Events to capture all T-SQL instructions failing. Use the sqlserver.error_reported event as shown below:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION azure_monitor
ON DATABASE

ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
ACTION (sqlserver.client_app_name, sqlserver.client_hostname, sqlserver.session_id, sqlserver.sql_text,
        sqlserver.username))
```